# Android tesseract OCR, jni :received a nullstring in Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

tesseract-android-tools-test (test project to ensure everything is set up right) works.
i got my eng.traindeddata from : http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/eng.traineddata.gz (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe)
Yet i still get the above mentioned error when trying to run my own path, which is just initializing it... that is all i am doing so far.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay even though the documentation states that you can call the init as tesseract.init(PATH, **null**) Then you cannot do so. Make sure you call it with "eng" or the language that you are looking to "interpret".

Answer (score 2):

You need to place eng.traineddata (unzipped) inside tessdata directory in your folder -

/mnt/sdcard/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Then, supply the path as /mnt/sdcard/ to your init call. 'tessdata' is added by the library..

```
public class TesseractApp extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File from = new File(sdcard, "Pic.jpg");
        TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
        api.init("/mnt/sdcard/", "eng");
        api.setImage(from);
        Log.d("OCR", api.getUTF8Text());
    }
}
```